# How do I use a variable in an SQL script passed in from a powershell script

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlcmd

I'm new to Powershell and getting stuck with some of the syntax. I have a powershell script that calls a SQL script with a variable I want to access inside the script.

```
param (
[string] $inst = "all"
)

invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "D:\PowershellScripts\testSQL\testScript.sql" -variable $powerShellVar=$inst -serverinstance '.\sql2008';
```

in my SQL query I want to be able to access the $powerShellVar variable like this

```
print $powerShellVar
```

However, when I do that, I get this error

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid pseudocolumn "$powerShellVar"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like variable quotation problem in the sql file. Add the sql script to the post too.

Comment: @von - I have. The only line it's got is the print statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter syntax is invalid. No wonder, as this is poorly documented. The `-variable` parameter assumes an array that contains name/value pairs like so,

```
$sqlParameters = @("variable1 = 'value1'", "variable2 = 'value2'")
```

For just a single parameter,

```
$sqlParameters = @("variable1 = 'value1'")
```

By this syntax, assuming printarg.sql contains `select $(powerShellVar)`, this ought work:

```
$sqlParameters = @("powerShellVar = 'foobar'")
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance computer\instance -inputfile "c:\temp\printarg.sql" -variable $sqlParameters
```

Comment: Hi, I've pasted exactly as you have stated into a powershell and sql script and I still get a "Invoke-Sqlcmd : Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. I think it's to do with select $(powerShellVar). Is there a command to check all the existing variables in the context of an sql query cause it looks like that the variable still doesn't exist.

Comment: actually I changed it to this $sqlParameters = "powerShellVar='foobar'" and it worked. thanks!